# Error handling after publishing events masstransit

Tags: c#, error-handling, masstransit

When using MassTransit, I was wondering how to handle exceptions after publishing an event. (not for consumers)
As you can see in code below, an exception occurs AFTER publishing an event, but before saving to the database.
Is there a way to "cancel" the published event, or does MassTransit handle this by itself?

```
public async Task Handle(RegisterCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var existingAccount = await _repository.GetByEmailAsync(request.Email);
    if(existingAccount is not null) throw new ConflictException("Account already exists");

    var account = _mapper.Map<Account>(request);
    await _repository.CreateAsync(account, cancellationToken);

    await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new AccountCreatedEvent{ Email = request.Email }, cancellationToken);

    throw new Exception();
    
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Entity Framework Core or MongoDB, the [transactional outbox](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/transactional-outbox) can be used to ensure events are only published when the transaction is successful.